# High volume elements and list and "strange" allocation memory

Tags: delphi, memory-management, delphi-xe2

In recent days I have seen something strange about Delphi memory allocation while working with a high volume of elements in a list.

My computer has 12 GB of ram; when I run my application in 64-bit mode (store data in list, high volume elements), I observe that memory used by my computer rises 10 GB slowly and after a short amount of time decreases until usage falls to almost 8 MB (normal size of the application when started in memory).
I thought: if I store data in memory, the size of memory used not should to be same? Because why is memory usage then going from 8 MB to 10 GB and falling back to 8 MB, when a large amount of data is every stored in memory and not cleared?

It is normal? Thanks for any suggestions.

**UPDATE**

I report full code, where is possible reproduce about i told before.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  PsApi, windows, System.SysUtils, System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TMyRecord = record
    x: Integer;
    y: Integer;
  end;
  TMyArr = array of TMyRecord;
  TMyList = TList<TMyArr>;

function CurrentMemoryUsage: Cardinal;
var
  pmc: TProcessMemoryCounters;
begin
  pmc.cb := SizeOf(pmc);
  if GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess, @pmc, SizeOf(pmc)) then
    Result := pmc.WorkingSetSize
  else
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;

var
  MyArr: TMyArr;
  MyList: TMyList;
  iIndex1, iIndex2: Integer;
  iMax: Int64;
begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    iMax := Low(Int64);
    Writeln(FormatFloat('Memory used before to create list: ,.# K',
      CurrentMemoryUsage / 1024));
    MyList := TMyList.Create;
    try
      Writeln(FormatFloat('Memory used before load item in list: ,.# K',
        CurrentMemoryUsage / 1024));
      for iIndex1 := 0 to 20000000 do
      begin
        SetLength(MyArr, 100);
        for iIndex2 := 0 to High(MyArr) do
        with MyArr[iIndex2] do
        begin
          x := iIndex2 + 1;
          y := iIndex2 - 1;
        end;
        MyList.Add(MyArr);
        if CurrentMemoryUsage > iMax then
          iMax := CurrentMemoryUsage;
      end;
      Writeln(FormatFloat
        ('Memory used (max) during to load item in list: ,.# K', iMax / 1024));
      Writeln(FormatFloat('Memory used to end load item in list: ,.# K',
        CurrentMemoryUsage / 1024));
    finally
      MyList.Free;
    end;
    Writeln(FormatFloat('Memory used after destroyed list: ,.# K',
      CurrentMemoryUsage / 1024));
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;

end.
```

As output i have something so:

```
Memory used before to create list: 3.452 K
Memory used before load item in list: 3.504 K
Memory used (max) during load item in list: 4.194.300 K
Memory used to end load item in list: 2.789.020 K
Memory used after destroyed list: 2.976 K
```

In this case, where tell "during load item in list" i get almost 4 GB, but after, when i have finished to load item in list memory used is almost 2-3 GB.
I have tried to do much simulation, this value changing, not are a constant, but in general respect this value.
I repeat, for me not much important it. Was just for understand more about allocation memory.

Comment: What's the specific question? Do you have a problem? And be specific about what you are measuring. "Memory of my comp is increase until to 10 GB" means nothing. You have to be precise.

Comment: Sorry, try to explain better. I have wrote a simple procedure that load in memory statistics data saving it in a list. This list contain much elements (in order of some million). No problem in particular. Just i have observed that during process to data, my application that take less of 8 MB of ram, slowly take more memory until to arrive to almost 10 GB. After, when process is terminated (not program) always slowly from 10 GB of ram back to 8 MB. When arrive to 8 MB the program terminate correcly. No problem in general, but i wanted know if this is normal.

Comment: I have thinked that if i need (for example: 1 GB or 10 GB) for stored all data, becouse then after not remain to this value, without back a 8 MB? In sense, data are correctly stored. Why delphy take all memory (100%) and after release it all until to 8 MB? Just a couriousity for understand better, but it not represent a real problem for me of course.

Comment: You did not address my comments.

Comment: I'm understanding clearly the subject of memory being used for 10GB of data, but I also am not understanding your question. This is more than normal, this is the way computers are designed to work. Unless I'm missing something in your *question*?

Comment: Are you expecting for the 10GB of allocated memory to suddenly drop all at once when your app is terminated? Because the gradual decrease is what it's supposed to do (normal). If it was a sudden drop from 10GB to 0GB then there's something wrong. All the allocated memory needs to be un-allocated, which can also be just as time consuming as allocating it in the first place.

Comment: @Jerry What are you talking about? Process termination returns memory to the system as soon as the process exits.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Depending on the code which actually destroys these objects anyway, nothing has been said about how long this "gradual" decrease takes. Freeing one of these millions of objects might take a split second, but the million all together is multiplied by this split second, and will happen over time. Killing the process without proper destruction of these objects will in fact instantly bring it to 0, but that doesn't mean you should forcefully kill the process at all. *proper* destruction of these objects could be time consuming, but doesn't mean it always is, time it takes varies.

Comment: To make a long story short, sudden drop of 10GB of Memory to 0 would suggest that the process was killed without properly destroying these millions of objects. But it was also not mentioned what these "statistics" are and how these objects are actually working. The Destructor might do something which takes time, and we don't know that.

Comment: @Jerry It's only you that's talking about dropping to 0. Nobody else is. Admittedly it's impossible to know what the question is actually about.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That was my only guess as to what was meant, I'm just trying to bring the real question to the surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your answers to the comments you are putting millions of entries into a list.  You havent specified the type of list but if its a TList or a decendant it will automatically grow the list to fit.

When growing the list it reallocates a new bigger array and coppies the old list into it, If you are adding millions of entries in a tight loop this will cause the reallocation of the internal list whenever the capacity is reached ( at least for TList ).

The memory for the old lists are not freed/made reusable immedialty and I belive this is the cause of your rather large memory use.

If you know the size of list you will need you should use the Capacity property to presize the array, if not put in some extra code in your loop to track the current count of the list and if close to capacity increase the capacity be a much larger value than the 25% it would do automatically.  That will drastically reduce the ammount of memory allocations and thus memory usage ( also better perfomance too ).

Hope that helps.

**Update**
Modified answer to remove incorrect list resizing information as pointed out be Kohi.

Comment: +1, both because I agree (although not sure if it answers the question), and also because you were showing 666...

Comment: Ok thanks, reading better your explanation i have understood about the reason of it. Thanks again.

Comment: with the code you have posted, yes i would expect to see what you are seeing, so I suppose yes it is normal behaviour, howver I would not reccomend such an approach for 20 mil entry list for the reasons i have stated.

Answer (score 1):

@Dampsquid is right, but TList descendents don't grow in fixed increments of 16 elements, and haven't done so for a long time (D3?). Once you get to 64 elements it grows by 25% on every resize. You can see this for yourself unless you're using the free version of Delphi. Ctrl-click on the TList declaration and have a look around. Add() calls Grow() which looks like this:

```
  procedure TList.Grow;
  var
    Delta: Integer;
  begin
    if FCapacity > 64 then
      Delta := FCapacity div 4
    else
      if FCapacity > 8 then
        Delta := 16
      else
        Delta := 4;
    SetCapacity(FCapacity + Delta);
  end;
```

You are still much better off even taking a guess at the eventual capacity. If you know you're going to be using millions of entries, start by setting the capacity to one million. That way you skip the 30-odd resize operations that it takes to grow your list to that million. I would be tempted to err the other way and guess the largest number you think you'll need. You "waste" 8 bytes per extra entry but avoid a bunch of reallocation and copy operations, so being wrong by a couple of million only costs you 16MB. When you're using GB of memory that's nothing.

(sorry for the answer, I don't have enough points to comment).